# How do I make the python help system show dynamically created classes in my dynamically created module?

Tags: python, python-2.7, documentation

I am dynamically creating a python module with dynamically created classes within that module.  However, when using the help function in python, the classes do not appear.  Here is an example of the issue.

```
import imp
Foo = imp.new_module("Foo")
Foo.Bar = type('Bar', (object,), dict(x=10, y=20))
help(Foo)
```

This shows the following.

```
Help on module Foo:

NAME
    Foo

FILE
    (built-in)
```

I would like Bar to show up in the **CLASSES** section.  How do I do that?

Note that `help(Foo.Bar)` describes the class as `in module __main__`.   Is that a clue?

```
Help on class Bar in module __main__:

class Bar(__builtin__.object)
 |  Data descriptors defined here:
 |  
 |  __dict__
 |      dictionary for instance variables (if defined)
 |  
 |  __weakref__
 |      list of weak references to the object (if defined)
 |  
 |  ----------------------------------------------------------------------
 |  Data and other attributes defined here:
 |  
 |  x = 10
 |  
 |  y = 20
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set the `__module__` of `Bar`:

```
Foo.Bar.__module__ = Foo.__name__
```

and it'll show up. `help()` filters out everything that is *not* part of the module, as per the `.__module__` attribute. The rest is assumed to be external imports.

Answer (score 1):

If you set `Foo.__all__` to include `'Bar'`, then `Bar` will be listed in the `CLASSES` section:

```
import imp
Foo = imp.new_module('Foo')
Foo.Bar = type('Bar', (object,), dict(x=10, y=20))
Foo.__all__ = ['Bar']
help(Foo)
```

Comment: This also works, but I think setting the __module__ is more appropriate for my needs.  Thanks for answering.